# Join 3 tables with where clause without common table

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables employee, sales, department

Employee table

```
------------------------------
  AssignemtID | EmployeeEmail
-------------------------------
      1       | abc.@cam.com
-------------------------------
      2       | bdc@cam.com
-----------------------------
      3       | dgs@cam.com
-----------------------------
      4       | tyr@cam.com
------------------------------
```

Sales table

```
Sales | EmployeeEmail     | Emp ID
------------------------------------
24333  | abc.@cam.com  |  34
------------------------------------
46373 | bdc@cam.com    | 24
-----------------------------------
32212 | dgs@cam.com    | 78
-----------------------------------
```

Department table

```
Department | Sales       |Emp ID
-------------------------------
AS         | 24333       |34
-------------------------------
we         | 46373       |24
-----------------------------
de         | 32212       |78
------------------------------
```

I want to see all the employee who are there in the Employee table but not in the Department table. the data is huge in all the 3 tables

Comment: What does the Sales table have to do with this?

Comment: Why doesn't the `Employee` table have an `Emp ID` column?

Comment: These tables don't make any sense. Why does the `Sales` table have emails, but no information about sales?

Comment: employee table and sales can be connected on Employeeemail. Sales and Department table on Sales figure, but cannot connect employee table  to department table as there is no common column

Comment: Employee table is a bit messy

Comment: there are sales in Sales column

Comment: I think all three tables mis-organized.  1-Employee Table didn't have an Id,2- You have to use string to join Employee table and Sales table. 3- Department table has two different Id to join etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect `Employee` to `Department` by joining it with `Sales`.

```
SELECT *
FROM Employee
WHERE EmployeeEmail NOT IN (
    SELECT EmployeeEmail
    FROM Sales AS s
    JOIN Department AS d ON s.Sales = d.Sales
)
```

or

```
SELECT e.*
FROM Employee AS e
LEFT JOIN Sales AS s ON s.EmployeeEmail = e.EmployeeEmail
LEFT JOIN Department AS d ON s.Sales = d.Sales
WHERE d.Department IS NULL
```